# Further study with bad scores after psychology undergraduate (Australia)

Tags: psychology, australia

I recently finished my Bachelor of Psychology degree with bad scores. I know honours is off the table for me but now I’m thinking that the Graduate Diploma of Psychology (Advanced) might be unavailable too.

My [scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKbO3.png) are entirely Cs and Ds. What are my options? I'm currently redoing one unit (intermediate psychology research methods).

Answer (score 2):

You say nothing about what your overall goals are, only that you have considered two different paths to gaining one more year of undergraduate education in psychology. From your choice of units in 3rd-year, it looks as if you might have entertained the idea of pursuing a career in clinical psychology or health psychology. The typical path in Australia would of course be to do an honours degree, followed by a Master of Psychology (Clinical), a PhD in clinical psychology, or a D.Psych ... and all those paths are likely to be currently blocked.

Most useful, I suspect, would be to devote some time to considering why your grades are not as good as you have hoped, and then to consider whether there are any obvious things you might do to correct the problem. Simple lack of smarts is not easy to overcome. On the other hand, if you were an ATAR entry student into university, your fundamental problem might simply be that you are still growing up, and that whatever is involved in that (independent structuring of your time and study, earning an income, supporting yourself at university, socialisation, or whatever) has taken more of a toll than you expected.

In that case, the solution might be to leave university studies, learn more about yourself and what you want to do, and then consider returning in three or four years time as a mature-aged student ... meaning, of course, older than the grand age of 22!